# Appodeal error when using the latest version

Tags: flutter, appodeal

How can I fix this error in stack_appodeal_flutter

```
E/Appodeal( 9569): Network [Error]: Your 'A4g' SDK version (21.0.0) doesn't match recommended. Please use 'A4g' SDK version 20.6.0 instead to be sure that everything will work correctly.
E/Appodeal( 9569): Network [Error]: Your 'Admob' SDK version (21.0.0) doesn't match recommended. Please use 'Admob' SDK version 20.6.0 instead to be sure that everything will work correctly.
E/Appodeal( 9569): Network [Error]: Your 'Notsy' SDK version (21.0.0) doesn't match recommended. Please use 'Notsy' SDK version 20.6.0 instead to be sure that everything will work correctly.
```

Comment: They have updated to 3.0.0 try to add package correctly check their instruction : https://pub.dev/packages/stack_appodeal_flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have updated to 3.0.0 try to add package correctly check their instruction :

https://pub.dev/packages/stack_appodeal_flutter